# Nomenclature not being assigned proper page number

Tags: environments, page-numbering, chapters, nomenclature

The following is my MWE:

```
\documentclass[12pt,twoside]{report}

\usepackage[intoc]{nomencl}

\newenvironment{preliminary}%
{\pagestyle{plain}\pagenumbering{roman}}%
{\pagenumbering{arabic}}

\makenomenclature

\begin{document}
\nomenclature{$m$}{The mass of one angel}

\begin{preliminary}  
\tableofcontents    
\printnomenclature[6cm]   
\end{preliminary}

\chapter{Should be on page 1}
text
\newpage
\chapter{Should be on page 2}
more text

\end{document}
```

Whats happening is that the nomenclature should be assigned a page value of ii as it is part of the preliminary environment however instead it is being assigned the page value 1.

Comment: Use the `\nomenclature` command in your body text to define a term, `\makenomenclature` in the preamble to create the list of terms, and `\printnomenclature` to insert the list of defined terms in the front matter. See section 2.1 of [the `nomencl` documentation](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/nomencl/nomencl.pdf)

Comment: modified the MWE according to your changes but still no luck

Comment: You have to issue `\clearpage` before a `\pagenumbering` command.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're not issuing `\clearpage` before changing the page numbering. What happens is that when the nomenclature is being typeset, a page is not filled and TeX sees `\pagenumbering{arabic}` before ejecting the page, so it changes numbering style and your nomenclature ends up having page number 1.

Add `\clearpage`.

```
% arara: pdflatex
% arara: nomencl
% arara: pdflatex

\documentclass[12pt,twoside]{report}

\usepackage[intoc]{nomencl}

\newenvironment{preliminary}
  {\clearpage\pagenumbering{roman}\pagestyle{plain}}
  {\clearpage\pagenumbering{arabic}}

\makenomenclature

\begin{document}
\nomenclature{$m$}{The mass of one angel}

\begin{preliminary}  
\tableofcontents    
\printnomenclature[6cm]   
\end{preliminary}

\chapter{Should be on page 1}
text
\newpage
\chapter{Should be on page 2}
more text

\end{document}
```