# Adding nomenclature to the preliminaries, page hyperlink wrong

Tags: hyperref, page-numbering, nomenclature

I am customising a thesis template to include my glossary. By default this was going in the end, but I want to have it in the front, in the preliminaries section before chapter 1, where a different line spacing and page numbering (roman) is used.

In the template `.cls` file I have now

```
...
\newenvironment{declaration}{   
  \chapter*{Author's declaration}
  \addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Author's declaration}  
}{}
\newenvironment{conventions}{% ! 
  \cleardoublepage
  \addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{\nomname}
}{}
```

Where I added myself the `conventions` environment. Then the preliminaries are creates as

```
\newcommand{\makeprelims}{
  \setcounter{page}{1}\renewcommand{\thepage}{\roman{page}}
  \pagestyle{empty} 
  \makecopyright
  \cleardoublepage
  \author{\iwroteit}    
  \maketitle
  \cleardoublepage
  \pagestyle{plain} 
  \begin{abstract}
    { \Large {\bfseries\sffamily {\@title}} \bigskip \par}
    {{\large \@author} \bigskip\par}    
    \input{prelims/abstract}    
  \end{abstract}
  \tableofcontents
  \listoffigures
  \listoftables
  \lstlistoflistings
  \begin{acknowledgements}    
    \input{prelims/acknowledgements}
  \end{acknowledgements} 
  \begin{declaration}
    \input{prelims/declaration}
  \end{declaration} 
  \begin{conventions}% !
    \input{prelims/conventions}
    \printnomenclature
  \end{conventions}
  \cleardoublepage   
  \setcounter{page}{1} 
  \renewcommand{\thepage}{\arabic{page}}            
  \pagestyle{fancy} 
}
```

Again, I just added the `conventions` stuff. The file `prelims/conventions.tex` simply consists of `\nomenclature` entries.

This works *almost* correctly, but the hyperlink in the table of contents for the conventions is wrong (although the page number is correctly printed). It actually points to the previous item ("Author's declaration"), as the following screenshot shows:

[image]

I ran nomenclature and latex multiple times, and there is no change in the behaviour, the hyperlink is still wrong. I looked at [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/154481/nomenclature-not-being-assigned-proper-page-number), but I do have a `\cleardoublepage` before `\printnomenclature`...

Answer (score 1):

The problem seems to be that `\printnomenclature` must be strictly *before* `\addcontentsline`. Removing the environment and directly pasting the following lines after `\end{declaration}` makes it work:

```
\cleardoublepage
\printnomenclature[2cm]
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{\nomname}
```

Comment: If the nomenclature spans multiple pages I guess the page number will be the wrong one. Isn't it simpler to load `nomencl` with the `intoc` option?

Comment: Ok, I will consider that; have to find out how `intoc` works. For now, since it is only one page, it works fine.